# How to set gradient background on table header?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: Sorry! Seems I'm an idoit. It is working, just the colours were too similar. Long day lol.

I am trying to get a gradient background on some table headers:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2fy4/

I have used the exact same code for gradients before an I can't understand why it's not working :-/

```
#content.postagepage table th.columnwidthbig {
color:#fff;
background-color: #3d9520;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #589D3D, #3d9520);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #589D3D, #3d9520);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #589D3D, #3d9520);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #589D3D, #3d9520);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #589D3D, #3d9520);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in FF this **is** working but the two colors #589D3D, #3d9520 are quite similar that at a first glance the gradient isn't really recognizable.

I changed the colors to `background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, yellow);` and it gets more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the changes, here is your edited css with [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fy4/9/) link. I have done the following changes in your css file.

```
#content.postagepage table th.columnwidthbig {
color:#fff;
background-color: #3d9520;
background: rgb(230, 16,21);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(230, 16,21) 30%, rgb(81, 4, 7) 70%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(230, 16,21) 30%, rgb(81, 4, 7) 70%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(230, 16,21) 30%, rgb(81, 4, 7) 70%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(230, 16,21) 30%, rgb(81, 4, 7) 70%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(230, 16,21) 30%, rgb(81, 4, 7) 70%);
text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```